# error CS1729: The type `UnityEngine.Rect' does not contain a constructor that takes `5' arguments

Tags: c#

Please Help Me. This error occures on like 39

Line 39:  GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 150, 200, 2000, 1000, "PLAYER ONE WINS"));

Please help me :c. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the closing brackets in the wrong place?

Try this:

```
GUI.Label (new Rect (Screen.width / 2 - 150, 200, 2000, 1000), "PLAYER ONE WINS");
```